# Magento when price = 0 show other message

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, request

I need a "simple" way to show Price on request when the price is 0 of a product.
I have used this methode but somehow it doesn't work: (my js path is correct)
http://www.designersandbox.com/magento/magento-hide-the-price-for-a-free-product-using-jquery/

My source:

```
<span class="price">€ 0,00</span>
```

The js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("span").each(function(i, e) {
        if ( (jQuery(e).attr('class') == "price") && (jQuery(e).text() == "€ 0,00") ) {
            jQuery(e).text("Price on request");
        }
    })
})
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: My fiddle works, must be some conflict??? http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/KAeRt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php to achieve this

```
 <?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
     <?php  echo 'FREE'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <!-- code that is currently displaying the price in your template -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

or you can use free extension here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zero-price-call-for-price-9426.html
:)

Comment: php works, thx would have been easier to use my first option :(

Comment: Ok if you really want to use jquery than it might help http://jsfiddle.net/DJBYR/1/

`jQuery(function() {

 var selectVal = jQuery('.price').text();
    var newVal = selectVal.replace(/\u20ac/g, ' ');
        var splitedData = newVal.split(',');
        if(splitedData[0] == 0 && splitedData[1]==0) {alert('its free'); }
       

} )`